# Fitting IGARCH model in Python

Tags: python, modeling, volatility

I'm new to GARCH processes. How can I fit an Integrated GARCH model to log-returns in Python?
By "How" I mean which library allows to specify unit-root GARCH model, or how to adapt existing tools. 
I am currently trying my way around [arch](https://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library, with little success. I note there is a constraint param  in the GARCH model, but unsure how to specify the unit-root requirement.

Any pointer would be most appreciated!

Thanks,